# Pegar parte do conteúdo da ID do SVG com PHP

Tags: php, regex, arquivo

Eu tenho um arquivo `SVG` e nele tem vários `paths` com a tag  e dentro da tag  tem o atributo **id** que por sua vez tem nome do estado e também do municipio (que é o que preciso pegar). Eu gostaria de pegar esse municipio com o `PHP`, fazendo um script pra ir lendo o arquivo e pegar dentro de cada atributo ID somente o municipio. O conteúdo do SVG é assim:

```
<g id="x5F_Bahia_x5F_Nova_Viçosa">
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#B3B3B3" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="0.2835" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
        M430.19,291.31l-0.01,0.21l-0.67,0.36l-0.42-0.06l0.17-0.4l0.33-0.01l0.29,0.08L430.19,291.31L430.19,291.31z M424.84,290.44
        l0.68,0.34l0.33-0.17l0.5,0.11l0.45,0.25l0.17-0.09l0.15,0.01l0.32,0.25l0.57,0.09l0.13,0.18l1.03-0.01l-0.15,0.27l0.04,0.31
        l-0.43,0.15l-0.44,0.26l-0.7,0.71l-0.19-0.15l-0.56-0.06l-0.4,0.12l-0.22-0.04l-0.41,0.17l-0.81-0.03l-0.38-0.11l-3.18,0.03
        L421,292.8l0.03-0.17l-0.39-0.05l-0.06-1.23l0.31,0.01l0.45-0.2l0.14-0.05l0.22,0.02l0.37,0.19l0.22-0.06l0.3,0.02l0.04,0.04
        l0.11,0.03l0.17-0.07l0.24-0.22l0.11-0.02l0.25,0.05l0.34-0.15l0.23-0.07l0.03-0.11l0.45-0.26l0.2,0L424.84,290.44L424.84,290.44z"
        />
    <path fill="#B3B3B3" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="0.2835" stroke-miterlimit="8" d="M430.19,291.31l-0.01,0.21l-0.67,0.36
        l-0.42-0.06l0.17-0.4l0.33-0.01l0.29,0.08L430.19,291.31L430.19,291.31z M424.84,290.44l0.68,0.34l0.33-0.17l0.5,0.11l0.45,0.25
        l0.17-0.09l0.15,0.01l0.32,0.25l0.57,0.09l0.13,0.18l1.03-0.01l-0.15,0.27l0.04,0.31l-0.43,0.15l-0.44,0.26l-0.7,0.71l-0.19-0.15
        l-0.56-0.06l-0.4,0.12l-0.22-0.04l-0.41,0.17l-0.81-0.03l-0.38-0.11l-3.18,0.03L421,292.8l0.03-0.17l-0.39-0.05l-0.06-1.23
        l0.31,0.01l0.45-0.2l0.14-0.05l0.22,0.02l0.37,0.19l0.22-0.06l0.3,0.02l0.04,0.04l0.11,0.03l0.17-0.07l0.24-0.22l0.11-0.02
        l0.25,0.05l0.34-0.15l0.23-0.07l0.03-0.11l0.45-0.26l0.2,0L424.84,290.44L424.84,290.44z"/>
</g>
<g id="x5F_Bahia_x5F_Novo_Horizonte">
```

Como podem ver tem **x5F_Bahia_x5F_Nova_Viçosa** e **x5F_Bahia_x5F_Novo_Horizonte**. O que preciso pegar é **Nova_Viçosa** e **Novo_Horizonte**. Como poderei fazer isso usando o PHP ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se for sempre o mesmo padrão (se o id tiver sempre '*x5F*' por ex) até escusa de usar regex, pode com php fazer:

```
$id = 'x5F_Bahia_x5F_Nova_Viçosa';
$exp = explode('_x5F_', $id);
$zona = end($exp);
echo $zona; // Nova_Viçosa
```

Com regex pode ser assim:

```
$id = 'x5F_Bahia_x5F_Novo_Horizonte';
$hey = preg_match('/_x5F_(.*)$/', $id, $matches);
echo $matches[1]; // Novo_Horizonte
```